# Export Database on Azure Keeps Locking

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I've been using the export database feature on Azure for the past year without problems.

However during the past week the feature seems to error more than it actually works. On some occasions the export takes an hour or more (where it used to be a minute or less) and on other occasions it errors without completing the job. On the Info Screen in Azure it says "Status - Pending" over and over again.

Does anybody know what I should do?  Should I create another container? Could there be something else wrong?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this happens from time to time due to Azure problems. For anybody who encounters this, the perfectly adequate workaround is to use Sql Server Management Studio, select the database and Export Data-Tier Application.

Here is another post on the same issue:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/bb66505e-7008-4555-b8cd-eec9ae25066f/unable-to-export-db-via-portal?forum=ssdsgetstarted